How can I manage client connection to an aks service?
I have an AKS cluster with a frontend service and a database service.
I setup a loadbalancer externally accessible to test that my app was working. I would like to authorize only users of my company to access the frontend, what is the best way to do this?
I already setup my clusters to use Microsoft Entra ID authentication with Azure RBAC. My goal would be to authorize only 2 user groups to access the frontend of my app.
EDIT: I saw this article but I don't find a way to use this approach with AKS
https://medium.com/@TakuSewo/azure-container-apps-authentication-functionalities-c5828b733ecc
Is it possible to use an Identity Provider with AKS?

Kubernetes doesn't offer anything in particular in the way of application-level authorization.  You'd have to implement authorization in your application itself.

As David mentioned, Kubernetes itself doesn’t provide native application-level authorization. If your goal is to control access to the Kubernetes resources then use Kubernetes RBAC with Azure AD, but if your goal is to control access to the actual frontend application then use the OAuth2 Proxy with NGINX Ingress and Azure AD method as a workaround, you can set up Azure AD authentication using an NGINX Ingress Controller with OAuth2 Proxy in your AKS cluster to secure your front end.
Create a Kubernetes Secret to store the OAuth2 Proxy client secret. You will get this client secret from the app registration->manage-> create new secret section.
kubectl create secret generic oauth2-proxy-secret \
    --from-literal=client-secret=<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET> \
    --namespace default


Deploy OAuth2 Proxy. I am using helm here to add and install the repository for the OAuth2 Proxy.
Why use OAuth2 proxy?
because it will handle Azure AD authentication and enforce group-based access control.
helm repo add oauth2-proxy https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/manifests
helm repo update

helm install oauth2-proxy oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy --namespace default --set config.clientID=<YOUR_CLIENT_ID> --set config.clientSecretSecretName=oauth2-proxy-secret --set config.config.clientSecretKey=client-secret --set config.config.provider=oidc --set config.config.oidcIssuerURL=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<YOUR_TENANT_ID>/v2.0 --set config.config.oidcGroupClaim=groups --set config.existingSecret=oauth2-proxy-secret --set config.config.redirectURL=http://<YOUR_DOMAIN>/oauth2/callback --set config.config.cookieSecret=$(openssl rand -base64 32 | head -c 32) --set config.config.cookieName=_oauth2_proxy


and to route traffic to your frontend service and integrate with OAuth2 Proxy.
update your ingress yaml like this-
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "http://oauth2-proxy.default.svc.cluster.local:4180/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "http://<YOUR_DOMAIN>/oauth2/start?rd=$request_uri"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: <YOUR_DOMAIN>
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend
            port:
              number: 80


Now when you will try to access your frontend from your domain, you should be redirected to the Azure AD login page. Only users who belong to the specified Azure AD groups will be granted access.
Reference-

Best practices for authentication and authorization in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)
OAuth2 Authentication

